# Need help identifying component from my couch

Tags: transistors

I am out of my depth with this, I need to identify this part. (to replace it)

This component is on a board that connects to the controls for the reclining motors.

Is there any additional information I can provide to help?

[image]

Comment: A clearer picture always helps. Also, if this circuit is duplicated somewhere else in the couch, a picture of an identical but undamaged part would probably be useful as well. Thirdly, if you can figure out and draw a partial or complete schematic of the surrounding circuit, that would provide some context for the chip, which could help in identifying it.

Comment: I can see about uploading a pic later of an undamaged part. But it will take a little while, the other board is an difficult spot. If it helps this is the original pic this came from: http://i.imgur.com/42XFwEz.jpg

Comment: Fairly probable that this is a Voltage generator. The 16BL is probably the date code (2016, 'BL' is more detailed), which is of little use. Maybe the -12 is the voltage, possibly 12V. The package seems to be D-PAK5. There is probably no complete component number, but if you can identify the logo, you might be able to convert the abbreviated code into the original part. (I don't recognize the logo...

Comment: Speaking to the manufacturer is the first port of call.